# javascript print weekend date

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hello Guys i want to show the week ending date in javascript or through some jquery calendar plugin with below functionality

**It looks something like this:**

Week Ending: **<** show weekending date in dd/MMM/YYYY format **>**

and then if we click on these left and right arrows it should show next weekend in same format.

kindly please suggest me if there is a plugin with similar functionality or if we can achieve this with simple javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```html
<html>
    <head>
 <script>      
     function myFunction(data) {
  if(data == "down")
      change = change - 7;
  else if(data == "up")
      change = change + 7;
     
  var someDate = new Date();
  var day = someDate.getDay();
  var numberOfDaysToAdd = 0;

  if(day == 1) { numberOfDaysToAdd = 5; }
  else if(day == 2) { numberOfDaysToAdd = 4; }
  else if(day == 3) { numberOfDaysToAdd = 3; }
         else if(day == 4) { numberOfDaysToAdd = 2; }
  else if(day == 5) { numberOfDaysToAdd = 1; }

  someDate.setDate(someDate.getDate() + numberOfDaysToAdd + change);
   
  var dd1 = someDate.getDate();
  var mm1 = someDate.getMonth() + 1;
  var yy1 = someDate.getFullYear();                 

                someDate.setDate(someDate.getDate() + 1);
                var dd2 = someDate.getDate();
                var mm2 = someDate.getMonth() + 1;
                var yy2 = someDate.getFullYear();

                var someFormattedDate = dd1 + '/'+ mm1 + '/'+ yy1 + '\n' + '&' +
             dd2 + '/'+ mm2 + '/'+ yy2;

                document.getElementById("showWeekends").innerHTML = someFormattedDate;
            }
 </script>
     </head>
     <body>      
 <button onclick="myFunction('down')"><</button>
 <span id="showWeekends"></span>
 <button onclick="myFunction('up')">></button>     
     </body>
     <script>
 var change = 0;
 myFunction("none");
     </script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

Use this to get the first and last day of week.

```js
var curr = new Date; // get current date
var first = curr.getDate() - curr.getDay(); // First day is the day of the month - the day of the week
var last = first + 6; // last day is the first day + 6

var firstday = new Date(curr.setDate(first)).toUTCString();
var lastday = new Date(curr.setDate(last)).toUTCString();

console.log("Week Start : "+firstday);
console.log("Weekend : "+lastday);

var date = new Date(lastday);
var formattedDate = date.getDate() + '/' + (date.getMonth() + 1) + '/' +  date.getFullYear();
console.log(formattedDate);
```

You can change `lastday` format manually using `getDay(), getMonth() and getFullYear()`

Comment: hi @atulquest93 this looks fine, but we do not need day and time format 22 Jan 2017 is enough also can we have that change to next and previous weekend functionality.

Comment: You can `var lastDate = new Date(lastday);` to convert `lastday` to date and then .. `lastDate.getDate()` to get day, `lastDate.getMonth()` and `lastDate.getFullYear()` and combine them in any format you want.

Answer (score 1):

Try This .

```
var current = new Date();     // get current date    
var weekstart = current.getDate() - current.getDay() +1;    
var weekend = weekstart + 6;       // end day is the first day + 6 
var monday = new Date(current.setDate(weekstart));  
var sunday = new Date(current.setDate(weekend));
```